# How to pass kwargs to __init_subclass__ when creating dynamic class

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

How can I pass values to `kwargs` parameter in the `__init__subclass__()` when creating a dynamic class with `type()`

```
class Base():
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        print (kwargs)

class Derived(Base, arg1='test_val'):
    pass


op: {'arg1': 'test_val'}
```

How can I do this with `type()` ?

```
type('newtype', (Base,), {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [types.new_class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html) instead of `type`. E.g.

```
from types import new_class

new_class('newtype', (Base,), {'arg1': 'test_val'})
```